# Java XStream - EOFException createObjectInputStream

Tags: java, xstream

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    java.io.EOFException
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:201)
    java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:613)
    java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:568)
    com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.binary.Token.readString(Token.java:153)
    com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.binary.Token$MapIdToValue.readFrom(Token.java:227)
    com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.binary.Token$Formatter.read(Token.java:186)
    com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.binary.BinaryStreamReader.readToken(BinaryStreamReader.java:153)
    com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.binary.BinaryStreamReader.moveDown(BinaryStreamReader.java:82)
    com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.binary.BinaryStreamReader.<init>(BinaryStreamReader.java:45)
    com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.binary.BinaryStreamDriver.createReader(BinaryStreamDriver.java:43)
```

I have no idea why. Only happens for some objects. Not all.

I am attempting to use **BinaryStreamDriver** when this happens. Normal toXML and fromXML operations works just fine.

Code used:

```
XStream XSTREAM = new XStream(new BinaryStreamDriver()) {
    // https://x-stream.github.io/faq.html
    {
        this.ignoreUnknownElements();
    }
};
```

Both these versions generate similar errors:

```
private Object readA(byte[] bytes) {
    try (
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream xdis   = STREAM.createObjectInputStream(bis);
    ) {
        Object o = xdis.readObject();
        
        xdis.close();
        
        return o;
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw Ex.runtime(e);
    }
}

private byte[] writeA(Object object) {
    try (
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream xdos   = STREAM.createObjectOutputStream(bos);
     ) {
        xdos.writeObject(object);
        xdos.flush();
        xdos.close();
        
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        
        return bytes;
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw Ex.runtime(e);
    }
}
```

and this:

```
private Object readB(byte[] bytes) {
    try (
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        BufferedInputStream dis  = new BufferedInputStream(bis);
    ) {
        Object object = STREAM.unmarshal(new BinaryStreamReader(dis));
        
        return object;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw Ex.runtime(e);
    }
}

private byte[] writeB(Object object) {
    try (
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream  dos = new BufferedOutputStream(bos);
    ) {
        BinaryStreamWriter writer = new BinaryStreamWriter(dos);
        STREAM.marshal(object, writer);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        
        return bytes;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw Ex.runtime(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like the methods are not *inside* the `XStream` declaration, which finishes with `};`

Comment: First thing I noticed about your code is that you are using try-with-resources which already handles the closable `.close()` and that since you are also closing in the try block, this might be a `.close()` call on an already closed resource.

Comment: Try not closing the resource, it should be closed after try block is done

Comment: @g00se no, they should not. the methods just uses those instances.

Comment: @SaleemKhair Unfortunately those has been added at a later point. First version was without the explicit close. The resource is closed again in try resource so it has no effect the second time.

Comment: > the methods just uses those instances< OK. The `@Override` threw me. The methods of what is being overridden? Also why are the `DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream` there - they seem to be redundant?

Comment: @g00se They are perhaps, but I just changed it and still the same. I think there might be a bug really. Unable to get around it. Will upload edit.

Comment: OK. Can we try a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: K, so what you said is true, the explicit `.close` will have no effect if the first close was **successful**.. but it just would introduce more complexity,  I think your problem is in encoding... is there a reason why aren't you using `FileOutputStream` and `FileInputStream` ?

Comment: XStream architecture is based on IO Readers and Writers, HierarchicalStreamDriver implementations respect encoding, but only if you provide an InputStream. If XStream consumes a Reader **you have to initialize the reader with the appropriate encoding yourself**, and any encoding definition in the XML header will be ignored.

Comment: So either: 
1) declare your encoding in your reader, or 
2) declare appropriate xml header in your file.

Comment: @SaleemKhair But I am using the same manner in which i encode and decode. I should be receiving them as I send them. Identically. The bytes in should be the bytes out. I could attempt to do this when I write the object to bytes, and try to read the object back from bytes right after. I would expect the same error to occur. Note that for the majority of objects serialized there are no issues. For some this issue occurs. I could try to set the encoding. I guess on the writer?

Comment: I think issue might be the on the back and forth for Jedis / Redis.

Comment: The Jedis library is using wrong mechanism. UTF-8. Is there a way to make the binary serilization UTF-8 compatible?

Comment: "The BinaryDriver cannot use character-oriented output streams."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235120/discussion-between-saleemkhair-and-mmm).